# PyQGIS legend with fixed size

Tags: pyqgis, legend, pyqgis-3

i want to export a qgis legend with specified width , height and dpi. but it crops the content

```
layout = QgsPrintLayout( QgsProject.instance() )
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.pageCollection().pages()[0].setPageSize(QgsLayoutSize( width, height, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutInches))
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
manager.addLayout(layout)

legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setTitle("title")

layerTree = QgsLayerTree()
for layer in layers:
    layerTree.addLayer(layer)

legend.model().setRootGroup(layerTree)
layout.addLayoutItem(legend)

exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter_settings = QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings()
exporter_settings.dpi = 256
inch_to_pixel = 96
exporter_settings.imageSize = QSize( inch_to_pixel * width , inch_to_pixel * height )
exporter.exportToImage(path, exporter_settings)
```

[image]

when i remove `layout.pageCollection().pages()[0].setPageSize(QgsLayoutSize( width, height, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutInches))`
it exports without cropping but this time its width and height are not fixed as i specified

[image]